# Showing informations on HTML using interpolation

Tags: json, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I need help with showing the information from my user to the HTML template. However, i can't figure out what i am doing wrong. Basically what i am trying to do is grab values from database, interpolate them into the main page to be displayed. The problem is with using the ngFor, i don't know where to apply this tag in my case. This is my HTML

```
<ion-header>
    <ion-navbar>
        <ion-title>DETALHES DA CONSULTA</ion-title>
        <ion-buttons start>
            <button ion-button (click)="dismiss()">
                <span class="txt">Fechar</span>
                <ion-icon ios="ios-close" md="md-close"></ion-icon>
            </button>
        </ion-buttons>
    </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
    <div padding-top class="card" *ngFor="let data of dataJSON">
        <div class="codigo">
            Código de confirmação da consulta: <strong>99887</strong>
        </div>
        <ul>
            <li class="categoria">
                <h2>Consulta em cardiologia - Geral</h2>
                <span>{{data?.agendaTeste?.Documento?.Especialidade}}</span>
            </li>
            <li class="data">
                Agendado para <span>05/09/2018</span> às <span>14:30</span>
            </li>
            <li class="medico">
                <span>Profissional executante:</span>
                <strong>Dr. José M. - CRM-SP 0000/000</strong>
            </li>
            <li class="ubs">
                <strong class="label">Local do atendimento:</strong>
                <div>
                    <strong>Unidade:</strong> SIMUS<br>
                    <strong>Endereço:</strong> Alameda dos Lírios, 327
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="cta">
            <button class="btn btn-danger btn-block btn-rounded">
                Cancelar consulta
            </button>
            <small>Caso não possa comparecer cancele ou reagende sua consulta.</small>

            <button class="btn btn-outline-midblue btn-block btn-rounded">
                Reagendar consulta
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</ion-content>
```

this is basically my code

```
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public modalCtrl: ModalController) {
    var query = firebase.firestore().collection("agendaTeste")
    var auxint = 0;
    this.dataAux
    let auxString = '[';
    query.where('Documento.Paciente', '==', this.paciente).get().then(res => {
        res.forEach(item => {
            if (item.exists) {
                auxint++;
                auxString += '{"id":"' + item.id + '","agendaTeste":' + JSON.stringify(item.data()) + '}';
                this.mostraHora = item.get("Documento.Hora");
                console.log(this.mostraHora);
                this.test = this.computeDateString(this.mostraHora);
                this.medicoid = item.get("Documento.Medico");
                this.especialidade = item.get("Documento.Especialidade");
                this.unidade = item.get("Documento.UBS");
                console.log(this.medicoid);
                console.log(this.especialidade);                    
                console.log(this.test);
                console.log(this.unidade);

            }
            if (res.size != auxint)
                auxString += ', ';
        })
        auxString += ']';
        this.dataJSON = JSON.parse(auxString);
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log('Ocorreu um erro ' + err);
    });

}
```

Whenever i try to render my information like this, i get an empty page, i tried logging into the console the information i am trying to display to the user and everything is good, so probably i am not rendering properly the ngFor

Comment: Can u please share the dataJSON structure? a screenshot is fine

Comment: its not relevant, besides its in the code all i do is declare it public dataJSON, and use it to store everything that was passed inside auxString.

Comment: if the dataJSON is not an array of items for loop won’t iterate.

Comment: Everything is fine with this part of the code. The problem is in HTML, the reason what makes me say that is that i have a similar page that is exactly like that one, and i literally just copied and pasted the code from there, the only thing that is different is the HTML, this issue happened because i was using the ng tag in the wrong place before, but now i can't see where to insert this tag to render it dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

```
<ion-content padding>
    <div padding-top class="card">
        <div class="codigo">
            Código de confirmação da consulta: <strong>99887</strong>
        </div>
        <ul *ngFor="let data of dataJSON">
            <li class="categoria">
                <h2>Consulta em cardiologia - Geral</h2>
                <span>{{data?.agendaTeste?.Documento?.Especialidade}}</span>
            </li>
            <li class="data">
                Agendado para <span>05/09/2018</span> às <span>14:30</span>
            </li>
            <li class="medico">
                <span>Profissional executante:</span>
                <strong>Dr. José M. - CRM-SP 0000/000</strong>
            </li>
            <li class="ubs">
                <strong class="label">Local do atendimento:</strong>
                <div>
                    <strong>Unidade:</strong> SIMUS<br>
                    <strong>Endereço:</strong> Alameda dos Lírios, 327
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="cta">
            <button class="btn btn-danger btn-block btn-rounded">
                Cancelar consulta
            </button>
            <small>Caso não possa comparecer cancele ou reagende sua consulta.</small>

            <button class="btn btn-outline-midblue btn-block btn-rounded">
                Reagendar consulta
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</ion-content>
```

my problem was solved after i added *ngFor inside the ul element.